# SQL Converting nvarchar with leading zeros to decimal

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have numbers which are 6 characters long with 3 implied decimal places. An example number would be 035000. So this is the number 35 [EDITED]. How can I go about converting this from `nvarchar` to a `decimal(6,3)`?

When I try `CAST(col as decimal(6,3)` I get the error:

> Arithmetic overflow error converting nvarchar to data type numeric.

I also tried parsing out the leading 0 using

```
select CAST(SUBSTRING(col, patindex('%[^0]%', col), 6) as decimal(6, 3))
from my_table
```

I got the same error message however. Or is this something I should leave in the DB as `nvarchar`, and convert in my C# code?

Comment: 035000 if we try to replace with 3 decimal places I think it will be 35. Are you sure about example?

Comment: Did you try casting it to an integer and then dividing by 1000?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot convert '035000' to a `NUMERIC(6,3)` because it has too many digits: the numeric representation of that number of 35000.000, which is 8 digits.

Since you know your numbers will always be 6 digits in your database, you should first convert to a `NUMERIC(6,0)` (or any other numeric type that can hold it -- `INTEGER` would work, for example) then divide by the correct factor to shift the decimal into place. (You said there were 3 implied decimal places, but your example shows 4 -- just use whichever conversion factor you need):

```
SELECT CONVERT(NUMERIC(6, 3), CONVERT(NUMERIC(6, 0), col) / 1000.0) FROM my_table
```

Comment: Just suggestion to use this WHERE col is not null and ISNUMERIC(col) = 1 clause so that it will not fail in case of characters or null values.

Comment: thanks that sounds like it should work. I'll test tomorrow and update as answer.